# Java FileReader vs File

Tags: java

I wanted to create a File/FileReader object to instantiate a Scanner object.

So, the text book had like this:

```
File file = new File("filename.txt");
```

However, our instructor was like, that is wrong, the correct way is:

```
FileReader file = new FileReader("filename.txt");
```

Both of them work. So, what's the difference between the two and which one's correct.

Comment: Define _work_. Both of those are meant for different purposes.

Comment: `File` is ony a file object. `FileWriter` is an object wich can write in a file. That are two very different things.

Comment: AFAIK `FileWriter` is to write a file while `Scanner` is to read a file. `File` class is meant to represent a file in the system.

Comment: One big difference is that there is a `Scanner` constructor which takes a `File` and there isn't one that takes a `FileWriter`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Work as in no compilation error when I use either of them to instantiate a Scanner object. Which one's use for what purpose, mate? Please elaborate.

Comment: Oh man....is the entire question wasted now? :(

Answer (score 7):

```
File(String name)
```

> Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string
>   into an abstract pathname. If the given string is the empty string,
>   then the result is the empty abstract pathname.

```
FileWriter(String name)
```

> Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name.

Basically, the difference is that only Instantiating a `File` won't allow you to write to it, while `FileWriter` does.

The constructor of `FileWriter` pass to `OutputStreamWriter` a new `FileOutputStream` which instantiate a `File` from the given name.

Note that a `Scanner` is used to read a `File` not to write in it.

---

**Edit :** To answer to your edited question where you changed `FileWriter` to `FileReader`, the main difference between  a `File` and a `FileReader` is that `File` does not have a `close` method while a `FileReader` does and implement `Closeable`. Most of the methods offered by `File` object are meant to manipulate directly the file (check existence, delete, create, list all files from directory). As @Pshemo mentionned, a `File` is not to be seen as data, but simply as a path.

I recommend to read the [File API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String)) and [FileReader API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html#FileReader(java.lang.String)).

Comment: I'm so so so sorry. I meant FileReader, now FileWriter. What now?

Comment: Additionally, a `File` object allows you to operate on the file (check for existence, delete, determine length, etc.  The `FileReader` object is just used for reading the file.

Comment: File doesn't need `close` method because it represents path, not data. FileReader on the other hand needs mechanism to release its locks on file. Anyway both `new Scanner(new File("path"));` `new Scanner(new FileReader("path"));` will work just fine so chose the one you want (I prefer `new Scanner(new File("path"));`).

Comment: Also, I was told that if I use the FileReader to instantiate a Scanner object, then closing the Scanner object will close the FileReader object automatically and we don't have to close the FileReader object again explicitly, is this true?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: Thanks mate. So, what does that mean? Obviously, one seems to have a close method and the other doesn't can either of them be used to instantiate Scanner class or is one of them recommended?

Comment: @Boyyett Most (if not all) Closable instances will also close resources they *wrap*. So yes, if you close Scanner which was initialized with `FileReader` then this reader will also be closed (that is why we shouldn't be careful with closing scanner which reads from `System.in`).

Comment: Honestly, I tend to use `new Scanner(new File("path"))` as it is shorter to write. Both of them will do near the same thing. Yes, both of them can be used.

Comment: @Pshemo: "That is why we shouldn't be careful with closing scanner which reads from System.in". Oh man... :( ....should we not close the Scanner object instantiated using the System.in object?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: Thanks again, mate. I guess for all practical reasons, they are indeed the same, eh?

Comment: @Boyyet they are not the same, but when implemented in a Scanner, the scanner will have the same behaviour yes.

Comment: @Boyyett "*should we not close the Scanner object instantiated using the System.in object?*" no if you want to read more data from user using `System.in` in your application current run. That is why I prefer to create one instance of Scanner and reuse it in my application if needed and to make compiler happy close it at the end of my app life-cycle.