# What is the difference between Java File+Scanner object for reading files and a FileReader object?

Tags: java, file, filereader

I was trying to find the difference between FileReader and the method I'm used to. I saw a question that was similar, but didn't really answer my question,it was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884384/java-filereader-vs-file). So here goes:
The method I'm used to goes like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
...
public static ArrayList<String> read_file(String filename)
{
    File temp = new File(filename);
    Scanner input_file;
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    try
    {
        input_file = new Scanner(temp);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.printf("Error: failed to open file %s\n", filename);
    return result;
    }

    while (input_file.hasNextLine)
    {
        String line = input_file.nextLine;
        result.add(line);
    }

    input_file.close();
    return result;

...
```

I get that the File object allows us to work with a file that exists in that String path/filename..

But what is the difference between what the File+Scanner combination here does and what the FileReader(File file) or FileReader(String filename) object does (I'm NOT asking about the different versions of FileReader, I get the idea of overloaded methods/constructors)?

It would help to explain what the FileReader does and how it's use would differ from a Scanner..

Thanks guys in advance.

Comment: The difference is that they are different, in ways which are sufficiently explained in the Javadoc. Specifically, `Scanner` is built *over* `FileReader` and friends.

Comment: Thanks, but I read Oracle's documentation about the FileReader before I asked this question. It wasn't that clear to me. That's why I asked... I appreciate the advice though. I'll take a look closer look at its methods and construction and try to work out how it works. While I have you here though, how do I close this question? I marked an answer as having answered my question, but I'm still getting notified about (less-than-helpful) comments.. Do I delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple words:

[Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html): A simple text scanner which can parse primitive types and strings using regular expressions. The advantage is programmers need to not worry about the writing implementation for parsing and converting the input data to various primitives. This fastens the development and reliable, because it is used by everybody and gets tested.

[FileReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html): Convenience class for reading character files or stream of characters. The functionality provided by `FileReader` is very limited to just reading the chars from the defined stream. The rest of the work has to be done the programmer.

**Conclusion**: The `Scanner` provide reliable and easy to use implementations for reading and parsing the streams (files), saves a lot of time in development.

Comment: So a FileReader only does pure text? Or is it like the char[] in C?

Comment: Don't know where you got those descriptions, but the *"need to not worry about the writing **efficient** implementation"* is incorrect (or misleading). `Scanner` is horrendously slow compared to a `BufferedReader`, especially if processing can be line-based. `Scanner` does provide a lot of nice features, but it's hardly efficient, unless you're only thinking of ease-of-use efficiency, not performance efficiency.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, `BufferedReader` is faster than `Scanner`, because it reads the data into the buffer and serves from the buffered memory as long as it can. But the all the nice parsing feature are not available with it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically a Scanner and a FileReader differ in their API. Meaning that you have different methods available to you for reading a file depending on which one you use. A Scanner attempts to tokenize your file, while a reader gives you access to more fine grained details. Also a Scanner is not specific to a file. It can read from many different input sources like the command line. While a FileReader is specific to reading a File.